# logcat have error about ArrayList

Tags: java, android

program not error but logcat error about index array list so picture I can't solve . please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mv = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    MapController mc = mv.getController();

    ArrayList all_geo_points = getDirections(16.821219, 100.260457, 13.913698, 100.510954);

    GeoPoint moveTo = (GeoPoint) all_geo_points.get(0);

    mc.animateTo(moveTo);

    mc.setZoom(12);

    mv.getOverlays().add(new MyOverlay(all_geo_points));

}


@Override

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {


    return false;

}



public static ArrayList getDirections(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {

    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" +lat1 + "," + lon1  + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric";

    String tag[] = { "lat", "lng" };

    ArrayList list_of_geopoints = new ArrayList();

    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.parse(in);

        if (doc != null) {

            NodeList nl1, nl2;

            nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag[0]);
            nl2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag[1]);

            if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {

                list_of_geopoints = new ArrayList();

                for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node1 = nl1.item(i);

                    Node node2 = nl2.item(i);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(node1.getTextContent());

                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(node2.getTextContent());

                    list_of_geopoints.add(new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6)));

                }

            } else {
                // No points found
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return list_of_geopoints;

}

public class MyOverlay extends Overlay {


    private ArrayList all_geo_points;

    public MyOverlay(ArrayList allGeoPoints) {

        super();

      this.all_geo_points = allGeoPoints;

    }


    @Override

    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow, long when) {

        super.draw(canvas, mv, shadow);

        drawPath(mv, canvas);

        return true;

    }

    public void drawPath(MapView mv, Canvas canvas) {

        int xPrev = -1, yPrev = -1, xNow = -1, yNow = -1;

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

    paint.setAlpha(100);

        if (all_geo_points != null)

            for (int i = 0; i < all_geo_points.size() - 4; i++) {

                GeoPoint gp = (GeoPoint) all_geo_points.get(i);

                Point point = new Point();

                mv.getProjection().toPixels(gp, point);

                xNow = point.x;

                yNow = point.y;

                if (xPrev != -1) {

                    canvas.drawLine(xPrev, yPrev, xNow, yNow, paint);

               }

                xPrev = xNow;

                yPrev = yNow;

            }

    }

}
```

}

This is code About google maps is line drive so input point latitude and longtitude two point for way line to driver and input is array . In code don't error but code have warning about array 8 wraning it all warning about array. run program have error logcat about array index.

---

01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.getgoogledirection/com.example.getgoogledirection.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at com.example.getgoogledirection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-18 00:37:29.720: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

Comment: You're really gonna have to post your logcat log

Comment: Why haven't you specified the subtype, `ArrayList<GeoPoint>`?

Comment: i already slove that problem so input <GeoPoint>but i still have problem it's doesnt work

Comment: but don't warning and logcat error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to help you, if you put the output of logcat here.
As you mention, the error probably comes from the method getDirections.

Comment: sorry before time .I cann't to picture logcat error.now I post charector that watch to difficult.

Comment: Your problem is that ArrayList, which is what has index 0?
What's in it? I recommend using this tool: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html for example: Log.d("ArrayList", "Error Array index 0: " + all_geo_points.get(0)); And as Sam says, I would recommend using generics.

Comment: Umm.. I test input <GeoPoint> but it's doesn't work and still to error logcat.

Comment: What is the value of lat and lng when you pass it as a parameter to GeoPoint object?

Comment: value of lat and lng will be used from ArrayList all_geo_points = getDirections(16.821219, 100.260457, 13.913698, 100.510954)
I ans u true ?? if no I'm sorry. I'm don't skill in to the write program. this code it from website . I'm test for study and does to my sernior project. please to help me. i don't known it. T^T